# How to remove the shading of a table's borders?

Tags: html, html-table

Image of problem:

[image: image of problem]

- Shadow lines ruin the map.

Location: http://etrian.wikia.com/wiki/Etrian_Odyssey_Wiki:Sandbox/test3/A1

I wish to make an editable map of levels in a game for a wiki.
Since the game has an in-game map drawing tool, we decided to use the same style as that (as seen in the image). The tiles have insides of 16x16 large.
On the tiles, you can place icons (as seen in the image, the 3 clover boxes are treasure).

However, one thing bothers me - I can't get these darned black lines out of my tables! Is there any way to remove these shadows?

Comment: VTC: Can no longer be reproduced: I don't have an old copy of the files related, and the issue is solved. Not only that; it's been a good 2 years, and I don't really know the details of the issue anymore. I just know it's fixed now and that it had to do with applying the border style... properly. Somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been pulling out my hair, until the admin of the wiki suddenly facepalmed and found that the CSS settings of the wiki overrode the border style of the table!

Solution:

```
border-style:solid
```